# Footer not displaying right, white gap at the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have a gap after the footer, you can see better here: http://imiodrag.dyndns.org:8080/club023/ **ONLY ON FIREFOX** , it's suposed to stick to the bottom, since is a sticky footer, but I can't find the problem, I've tried two days and can't find a solution, mabe you guys can give me a hint or something.

Comment: I'm seeing the whitespace on IE 9 as well

Answer (score 3):

This is how I got it:

Added `overflow:hidden` to the footer.

Answer (score 2):

It is the `margin-top: -0.3125em;` on the class `.social` in screen.css?ver1 line 215.

That line is shifting the whole body up ~10 pixels leaving the gap under the footer.

Comment: Removed and the gap is still there

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you remove the margins on the html and body tags:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Some browsers add margins/paddings to these tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your problem is caused by the white space after your `<footer>`.

```
</footer>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://imiodrag.dyndns.org:8080/club023/wp-content/themes/club023/js/lib/jquery-latest.min.js?ver=x'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=x'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://imiodrag.dyndns.org:8080/club023/wp-content/themes/club023/js/lib/thickbox-compressed.js?ver=x'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://imiodrag.dyndns.org:8080/club023/wp-includes/js/hoverIntent.js?ver=20090102'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://imiodrag.dyndns.org:8080/club023/wp-content/themes/club023/js/lib/jquery.noisy.min.js?ver=x'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://imiodrag.dyndns.org:8080/club023/wp-content/themes/club023/js/script.js?ver=3'></script>
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script src="http://imiodrag.dyndns.org:8080/club023/wp-content/themes/club023/js/lib/selectivizr.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<![endif]-->
</body>
```

I would recommend putting **everything** between `<footer>` and `</body>` into a `<div>` that you size to be 0x0. Make sure there isn't *any* white space at all between `<footer>` your new `<div>` and the `</body>`.

Comment: Removed the whitespace same thing

Comment: You got rid of all of the white space *including* line-breaks and it still happened?